# Rails 5: Is is possible to print out a page with a different language locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, printing

I am printing out a 'receipt' page using the following:

`link_to '', :onclick => 'window.print();return false;',`

Is it possible to view the page in a locale like `en` but print it out in a different one like `de`?

Example: An English speaking user could use the system in Germany, but all the printouts would still be in German. This would allow users to use the system in their own native language, wherever the company or organization is based.

Also, is this this the best way to print out a page in rails?

I tried hacking with the `I18n.with_locale() do` but did not figure out a nice way to do this. Preferably passing a locale string to the print function or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to this:

1) do it on the frontend using CSS: use the `lang` attribute throughout the page, creating two elements for every text on the page. Hide one of the languages by default (i.e. `:lang(de) { display: none }` and use `@media print` CSS to show it, hiding the other one at the same time. You can apply other CSS styling to do things like hiding navigational elements etc.

2) open a new window which contains the document in the other language. Probably less surprise to the user. You can pass the desired locale in the URL and have it trigger the `window.print()` JS in the `onload` event handler.

3) directly generate a PDF on the server, probably using a different format in your `show` action. This gives you more control over the actual layout without relying on the behaviour of the browsers of your users. There are a few libraries for this, one of them being https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_pdf